# Getting Uncaught TypeError while calling Titanium.Filesystem.getSeperator on Android

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Was trying to use the function `Titanium.Filesystem.getSeperator` on Appcelerator and it works well on ios. However on Android we got the following error:

```
[ERROR] V8Exception: Exception occurred at /scripts.js:1: Uncaught TypeError: Titanium.Filesystem.getSeperator is not a function
```

Anyone has any idea? Tried to google but nothing..

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your code. It is not `seperator` but `separator`. Why it works on iOS baffles me.

Always check the [docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Filesystem-method-getSeparator) and verify your code. When it says method is not defined, it should ring a bell

Comment: I think Titanium-iOS handles that typo error internally somehow.